# How to Convert certain rows in a Pandas Data frame to Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

What will the be easiest way to do this??

Comment: what happens to `h3` & `h4`? you had a perfectly good [mcve] don't use images please see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
out=df.set_index('H1').unstack().to_frame().drop_duplicates(subset=0).T
```

Finally:

```
out.columns=['a1','a2','a3','H3','H4']
```

output of `out`:

```
    a1  a2  a3  H3  H4
0   b1  b2  b3  c1  d1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.to_dict` and `.join` to create a new dataframe.

```
# note you'll need to set an index if you only have 1 row.
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df.set_index('H1')['H2'].to_dict(),index=[0]).join(df.iloc[:,2:])


print(new_df)

   a1  a2  a3  H3  H4
0  b1  b2  b3  c1  d1
```